# Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex rewrite all my module links

Tags: zend-framework, zend-route, zend-router

I'm using Zend_Framework 1. In my Bootstrap.php I rewrite my categories link something like that:

```
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex("^([a-z,0-9,-]*)(/|)([a-z,0-9,-]*)(/|)([a-z,0-9,-]*)(/|)([a-z,0-9,-]*)(/|)([a-z,0-9,-]*)(/date/|)([a-z]*)(/page/|)([0-9]*)$",
        array(
           "module" => "default",
           "controller" => "categories",
           "action" => "index"
        ), 
        array(
                1 => 'firstparam',
                3 => 'secondparam',
                5 => 'theeparam',
                7 => 'fourparam',
                9 => 'fiveparam',
                11 => 'date',
                13 => 'page',

            )
    );
    $router->addRoute("RouteCategories", $route);
```

The problem is that all my admin links  (a module I use)  are now enter this condition. Is there any way to apply this condition only to module: default without rewrite all my admin links? Thanks

Comment: I recommend you to prefix your categories urls.
Example:
`$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex("^category-([a-z,0-9,-]*)(/|)([a-z,0-9,-]*)(/|)([a-z,0-9,-]*)(/|)([a-z,0-9,-]*)(/|)([a-z,0-9,-]*)(/date/|)([a-z]*)(/page/|)([0-9]*)$",`

Comment: Thank you! I thought to this posibility, but wasn't sure the client would accept this solution. But he did :)