# Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex - please help me with the fourth parameter

Tags: zend-framework, zend-route, zend-router

I have this example:

```
    $route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex(
    'blog/archive/(\d+)-(.+)\.html',
    array(
        'controller' => 'blog',
        'action'     => 'view'
    ),
    array(
        1 => 'id',
        2 => 'description'
    ),
    'blog/archive/%d-%s.html'
);
$router->addRoute('blogArchive', $route);
```

Can anyone tell me what /%d , %s means ?
For example if a have a code like this:

```
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex("^([a-z,0-9,-]*)(/|)([a-z,0-9,-]*)(/|)([a-z,0-9,-]*)(/|)([a-z,0-9,-]*)(/|)([a-z,0-9,-]*)(/date/|)([a-z]*)(/page/|)([0-9]*)$",
        array(
           "module" => "default",
           "controller" => "categories",
           "action" => "index"
        ), 
        array(
                1 => 'firstparam',
                3 => 'secondparam',
                5 => 'theeparam',
                7 => 'fourparam',
                9 => 'fiveparam',
                11 => 'date',
                13 => 'page',

            )
    );
```

how can i write the last parameter ( 'blog/archive/%d-%s.html') linke in the example. Thank you!

Comment: Why did you post two questions on the same issue / problem? [The Other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21331059/zend-controller-router-route-regex-rewrite-all-my-module-links)

Comment: it's not the same question. I want to write the fourth parameter so I can use $this->url. The other was about "haw to avoid this rule to be applied to all my links"

Answer (score 1):

`%d` means digit and `%s` means string.

`[a-z,0-9,-]*` is a regex. Read up more [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/php.html).